# Django not redirecting properly

Tags: python, django, redirect, nginx

My django website is running at `http://localhost:8000`. I'm trying to redirect them back to the root url of the website but it's not working properly. It keeps trying to redirect me back to `http://localhost` and dropping the port. What am I doing wrong?

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class Register(View):

    def post(self, request):
        return redirect('/')
```

This is my `home/urls.py` file:

```
from home.views import (
    Index,
    Feed,
    Search,
    Profile,
    Register,
    Login,
)

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view()),
    url(r'^feed$', Feed.as_view()),
    url(r'^feed$', Feed.as_view()),
    url(r'^search$', Search.as_view()),
    url(r'^profile$', Profile.as_view()),
    url(r'^profile/(?P<id>\d+)/?(.+)$', Profile.as_view()),
    url(r'^register$', Register.as_view()),
    url(r'^login$', Login.as_view()),
    url(r'^login$', 'login', name='login'),
)
```

And in `app/urls.py` I have this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^favicon\.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url="%simg/favicon.ico" % django.conf.settings.STATIC_URL)),
    url(r'^', include('home.urls')),
)
```

FWIW I'm using vagrant and running nginx on the vm. I have nginx listening on port :80 in the vm and I have my local port 8000 forwarded to port :80 on the vm which in turns routes it to port :8000 on the vm. I'm launching the site by running `python -B manage.py runserver 8000`

Comment: What does your `urls.py` look like?

Comment: @Micah does `return HttpResponseRedirect("/")` work?

Comment: No HttpResponseRedirect("/") does the same thing.

Comment: are you using the internal `runserver`, apache-passenger or `nginx` or another wsgi compatible server?

Comment: I updated the answer to include how it's setup

Comment: `Location:`-redirects use the hostname/port from the incoming `Host:`-header.  I think you need to configure nginx: send the correct `Host:`-header or fix the `Location:`-header.  http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.30

Comment: Put a `print request.get_host()` in your `Register.post()` method. `request.META["HTTP_HOST"]` might also be helpful. Also check out [USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#use-x-forwarded-host), but nginx will also need to be configured to set that header (no idea if it's the default or anything)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few issues here.

1. You should not be forwarding 8000 to anything. You should have nginx listening on port 80, and then add an upstream server which points to 127.0.0.1:8000 and launch runserver on that port.  Once you have done that, your URLs should all be without a port. Forward port 80 from the vagrantfile to your host if you want the links to work.  Or you could avoid all this unpleasantness by removing nginx from your setup.
2. URL patterns don't match query strings `url(r'^profile/(?P<id>\d+)/?(.+)$', Profile.as_view()),` won't pass the second match as an argument.  You also have duplicated patterns.
3. Finally, consider naming your views. It is a good habit to get into.  It also helps with redirection.

Comment: The issues was definitely nginx related. It's fixed now. Can you tell me more about what you mean by "naming your views"?

Comment: @Micah - check [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[`Location:`-redirects](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30) use the hostname/port from the incoming `Host:`-header. I think you need to configure nginx: send the correct `Host:`-header or fix the `Location:`-header.

Try something like this (from http://wiki.nginx.org/LikeApache and http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect)

```
server {
  listen myhost:80;
  server_name  myhost;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
    proxy_pass http://myapp:8080;
    proxy_redirect http://myapp:8080/ http://myhost/;
  }
}
```